# RegEX to parse and loop multiple custom tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse the following data by looping through each matcc, but the expression is grabbing the first[FILE] all the way to the last [/FILE]. I want it to iterate EACH custom tag.

Data:

```
"[FILE]file_1.png[/FILE]<br /><br /><br />[FILE]file_2.png[/FILE]"
```

Results:

```
file_1.png<br /><br /><br />file_2.png`
```

.

```
    var urlRegex = /(\[FILE\]).*(\[\/FILE\])/ig;
    text = text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {

        url = url.replace(/\[.?FILE\]/ig, "");

        var path = "./uploads/" + $('#CURRENT_FOLDER_UID').val() + "/";
        var res = "";

        arr = url.split(".");
        ext = (arr[arr.length - 1]).toLowerCase();

        if (img.indexOf(ext) > -1) {
            //url = encodeURI(url);
            res = '<img src="' + path + encodeURI(stripHTML(url)) + '" />';
        } else {
            res = '<a href="' + path + encodeURI(stripHTML(url)) + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
        }

        return res;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\[FILE\]).*?(\[\/FILE\])
```

Try this.Make your `*` non greedy by putting `?` after it.`*` is greedy by default.It will upto last `[/FILE]

You can also try `\[FILE\]|\[\/FILE\]`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/4

```
var re = /\[FILE\]|\[\/FILE\]/gm;
var str = '[FILE]file_1.png[/FILE]<br /><br /><br />[FILE]file_2.png[/FILE]';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Looks this did it... wow. Thanks for the quick response. I'm testing a bit more and will probably make this answered.

Comment: You can accept it now, as he's correct. The `?` makes the 'match X, followed by anything, followed by Y' non-greedy. By default, 'match X, followed by anything, followed by Y' matches everything between the first 'X', and the last occurrence of 'Y', whilst the `?` tells the regex engine to stop at the first result.